# Cordova, como mudar a cor da barra de controles: voltar, home e janelas

Tags: android, apache-cordova

não sei ao certo o nome do componente mas a imagem abaixo esclarece oque eu preciso, desde já peço desculpas...

Preciso alterar a cor deste componente no cordova

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendo em vista que o [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) transforma HTML5 + CSS + JavaScript em código nativo, você terá que fazer uma adaptação do código original básico para  alteração da cor do `NavigationBarColor`. Abaixo segue duas formas, tanto via XML quanto programaticamente, usando JAVA. Veja:

**XML**

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

**JAVA**

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

No entanto existem alguns *plugins* no qual você pode estar usando. Como por exemplo, o [**cordova-plugin-navigationbar-color**](https://libraries.io/npm/cordova-plugin-navigationbar-color). Como está com o código aberto, você mesmo pode estudar e adaptar de acordo com sua necessidade. Veja como ficaria:

```
window.NavigationBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#3F51B5');
```

<sup>**Nota**: o método foi introduzido no [Android Lollipop](https://www.android.com/intl/pt-BR_br/versions/lollipop-5-0/) e não funcionará na versão da API < 21.</sup>

Comment: interessante irei testar

Comment: poderia citar um exemplo de como usar ?
em qual xml eu coloco esta propriedade, no config.xml ?

e o meto ali, é javascript ?

como posso alterar para a cor : #3F51B5

Comment: @JeffersonMelloOlynyki Você chegou a instalar esse plugin?

Comment: sim, ja instalei

Comment: @JeffersonMelloOlynyki dê uma olhada aqui nesse arquivo, onde o cara faz a alteração usando o plugin: https://github.com/fagundes/cordova-plugin-navigationbar/blob/master/www/navigationbar.js

Comment: perfeito @Ack Lay
window.NavigationBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#3F51B5');
Obrigado !

Comment: @JeffersonMelloOlynyki editei a resposta e coloque seu código lá, pois pode ajudar outras pessoas. Abs. boa sorte.

Comment: opa, beleza, vai ajudar que estiver com dúvidas, obrigado